# What does my iPhone see/track when connected to my macbook PC?

Tags: privacy, logging, iphone, user-tracking

Recently hooked up my work iPhone to my personal MacBook to charge the phone.  I viewed some websites that would be questionable on the MacBook using the hotel WiFi.

What does the iPhone track when it is hooked up through USB to the MacBook; i.e., does it track the content viewed using the PC?

Answer (score 1):

Your iPhone won't directly see what you did on your mac while you're charging it. But there's a catch: **your browsing history might be [synced](http://www.tekrevue.com/safari-sync-browser-history/) via the cloud**. If:

- You were browsing using Safari
- You were *not* browsing in "incognito"
- You have iCloud sync activated
- You're logged on your iPhone with the **same Apple user** as the one used on your mac

I'm pointing this out in case you used your personal Apple user on the iPhone e.g. to download apps without creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can not because you are just charging it.

That is not possible even in the case you changed the settings of your phone so that you shared the Internet via your USB cable to use it with your laptop ([Sharing your phone's Internet connection by USB tethering](http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-one/howto/365713.html)). But both in the first scenario (using the hotel's Wi-Fi) and this later one, an attacker could spy your online activities in different manners.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say it wont track anything at all. I dont know your configuration. Nowadays you can never take something for granted. If its really private; do anything at all to prevent the risks which are involved.